# Why a binary filename field is missing in a Transient Model in Odoo 9?

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, odoo, odoo-9

I created a `TransientModel` which has a binary field expecting a ZIP file, thus I want to work with its filename to check that the file uploaded by the user is actually a ZIP. So I did as always:

**CODE**

**XML**

```
<field name="filename" invisible="0"/>
<field name="source_file" widget="binary" filename="filename"/>

<button name="import_zip" string="Import" type="object" class="oe_highlight"/>
```

**Python 2.7**

```
class EasyImport(models.TransientModel):
    _name = 'easy.import'

    source_file = fields.Binary(
        string='Choose a ZIP File',
        required=True,
    )
    filename = fields.Char(
        string='Filename',
        readonly=True,
        required=True,
    )

    @api.onchange('filename')
    def onchange_filename(self):
        _logger.critical(self.filename)  # Returns the filename OK

    @api.multi
    def import_zip(self):
        self.ensure_one()
        _logger.critical(self.filename)  # Returns False
```

**PURPOSE**

Reject non-ZIP files. Or at least, read the field `filename`.

**THE PROBLEM**

The `filename` field is always `False` (except in `onchange` method).

I tried to get its value in a constraint, in the `import_zip` method... but it returns `False`. However, I can see the filename in the interface as I am showing the field `filename` in the XML view, and it is right and automatically filled in.

I have an ugly workaround with a computed field to work with the filename, but I want to improve this and know what is happening here.

Any ideas? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not related to transient models nor binary fields nor any of those.

The field `filename` is readonly and I have just realised what happened with readonly fields combined with `onchange` methods, there is a big mistake in Odoo, in my opinion, still with no fix -at least in version 9-:

> If you modify a readonly field in an `onchange` event, you can work OK
>   with its new value until you save the record. When this happens, the
>   new value turns into the old one, and every method which uses it will
>   get the old value.

In my case, I saw the `filename` OK in the `onchange` method because the record was not saved, but when I clicked on the button which executes `import_zip` method, before executing its content, the record is stored and due to the Odoo mistake the `filename` value was replaced by its old value (which is always `False`).

So basically the solution is making not readonly the field `fieldname`:

```
filename = fields.Char(
    string='Filename',
    readonly=False,
    required=True,
)
```

And in XML make it invisible to avoid inconsistencies:

```
<field name="filename" invisible="1"/>
```